# SQL - Compare two columns find the true value and use the value in IF calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I am trying to compare two columns page_entry & exit_page if both true value of 1 then its a bounce.

```
Page_entry |  exit_page | Bounce 
    1             1        true
    0             1        false 
   etc           etc       ......
```

this is what I came up with and it only shows me the true values

```
select hit_id,visit_num,
    CASE 

        WHEN entry_page = exit_page
        THEN 'True'
        ELSE 'False'

    END as Bounce
FROM [dbo].[Primary]
WHERE entry_page = exit_page
END
```

BUT now I need to write a calculation like

```
SUM(IF Bouce = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/page_visit
```

Comment: What's `page_visit`? I don't see that in your example data.

Comment: Your `WHEN` and `WHERE` clause are the same!  So yes it's going to only show `TRUE`.

Comment: Replace: `CASE WHEN entry_page = exit_page THEN 'True' ELSE 'False'  END as Bounce` with `SUM(CASE WHEN entry_page = exit_page THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Bounce`

Comment: Page_entry entry_page.   WHERE entry_page = exit_page and you wonder why all true.   Sum and no group by.

Comment: page_visit is a country of how many times a page was hit sorry I didnt include it in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? :

```
select hit_id,visit_num,
    SUM (CASE entry_page 
        WHEN exit_page THEN 1
        ELSE 0      
        END)/page_visit as ratio
FROM [dbo].[Primary]
group by hit_id,visit_num,page_visit ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN entry_page = 1 AND exit_page = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END as 'BounceAnswer'

SUM(CASE WHEN entry_page = 1 AND exit_page = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'BounceCount'
```

Answer (score 0):

select hit_id,visit_num,
    SUM (CASE entry_page 
        WHEN exit_page THEN 1
        WHEN entry_page THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END)/visit_num as ratio
FROM [dbo].[Primary]
group by hit_id,visit_num,entry_page;

this got me close enough thanks!!!!!